# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

The terminal says that is a warning in this line:

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
>   default]

```
while ((dirzeiger=readdir(dir)) != NULL)
```

I can't find the mistake...

```
void ls () {

struct dirent {

    long d_ino;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    unsigned short d_namlen;
    char *d_name;
};

DIR *dir;

struct dirent *dirzeiger;

if ((dir =opendir("/home/Bernardinho/Schreibtisch")) != NULL)

  while ((dirzeiger=readdir(dir)) != NULL)

     printf("%s\n",(*dirzeiger).d_name);

}

int main( int argc, char* argv) {

ls();

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Mr.32 stated, you forgot to include the necessary header file. Besides, it seems that you redefined the structure `dirent`. Hence, `dirent` as considered by `readdir` is different from your `dirent` and the pointers are not compatible.

Comment: but i have add the header #include <dirent.h> . could you told me how t make them compatible?

Comment: @BernardDarrylOungouande if you've included the proper header, you shouldn't need to redefine the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to include

```
#include <dirent.h>
```

Without Header file include any function with implicate declaration will have return type of integer. so readdir() will be taken as return type of int and you are storing its return in pointer so you get that warning.

You can see after adding heade file you do not have any warning.

http://codepad.org/2YZWcrVP